# How to stop MongoDB to add values to my objects?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, journaling, database

I'm writing a little personal project requiring to write into a db and getting content to be displayed with d3js. So I'm using objects containing like `{x: "2004-10-02", y:20}` etc... Now I found that mongoDB adds  `y0:0` and even  `y1: 20` when I change the value of `y` using  `$set` with Mongoose.

I have this `Schema`:

```
var projectSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   key : String, 
   description: String,
   values: [{x: Date, y: Number, comment: String}]
});
```

It works fine. I can insert documents (incomplete model) sending a request with this body:

```
{
    name: "name of the Project", 
    description: "insert descritption"
}
```

and process the request with this:

```
var newProjectDetails = req.body;
var np = new Project(newProjectDetails);
np.save(function (err) {
  if (err) {
        return err;
  }
  else {
    console.log("Project saved");
  }
});
```

then I add values to the `values` array (see above the Schema) and it works fine the first time, but if I try to overwrite an entry in the array I get this a messed object, with extra values that seem to be old values of the `y` property.

Here's how I add an entry into the `values` array:

```
Project.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body._id, 
   { $set: { values: req.body.values } }, 
   function(err, tank){
     if(err){
       res.send(err);
     } 
       res.send(tank);
   })
```

But then when I fetch the content I got a strange issue inside the array:

I get this object in the console:

```
  {
    "x": "2014-10-12T00:00:00.000Z",
    "y": 20,
    "comment": "doanjas dfgixGHWXV",
    "_id": "543a96c3a402c9ad17528d52"
  }
```

and this in RestWebServiceClient extention in Chrome:

```
{
  "x": "2014-10-12T00:00:00.000Z",
  "y": 20,
  "comment": "doanjas dfgixGHWXV",
  "_id": "543a96c3a402c9ad17528d52"
}
```

But inside the console, when I iterate through the collection with Angular I get this:

```
{ _id: "543a96c3a402c9ad17528d52", 
  comment: "doanjas dfgixGHWXV", 
  series: 0,
  size: 20, 
  x: "2014-10-12T00:00:00.000Z", 
  y: 20, 
  y0: 0, 
  y1: 20
}
```

This is driving me crazy, should I map the array and get rid of this, why would I do that extra work?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code that's performing the `$set` that's causing this? This won't normally occur.

Comment: I don't see a `values` field in your doc like you have in the `$set`.

Comment: the object giving trouble is in the content of the doc: imagine  `values: [{x:"2014-05-20", y: 35, comment: "a comment"}]`

Comment: Hmm...this is pretty confusing. I think you're going to need to provide a complete example.

Comment: By complete example I mean a block of server-side code that can be run against an example collection doc that includes the data that reproduces the problem you're seeing.